# PHP return object variables inside of an array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a PHP script to work with some JSON data. Below is an (abridged) `var_dump($data)`. I want to return the value associated with `["[question(13), option(0)]"]` which is 20. I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried `$data->[question(13), option(0)]` and `$data->question(13)`. (I tried to look this up but I'm not sure what the notation means, so I'm not sure what I'm looking for)

```
object(stdClass)#133 (36) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["contact_id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["status"]=>
  string(8) "Complete"
  ["is_test_data"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["datesubmitted"]=>
  string(19) "2012-04-19 17:11:00"
  ["[question(5)]"]=>
  string(11) "C.    40%, 40%"
  ["[question(9)]"]=>
  string(47) "D.    EBITDA and Free cash flow are the same thing"
  ["[question(10)]"]=>
  string(48) "A.    Accounts Payable as % of sales would increase"
  ["[question(11)]"]=>
  string(20) "E.    None of the above"
  ["[question(12)]"]=>
  string(97) "A.     A larger portion of initial investment is equity which can increase exit return potential."
  ["[question(13), option(0)]"]=>
  string(2) "20"
  ["[url("embed")]"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["[variable("STANDARD_IP")]"]=>
  string(13) "38.107.74.230"
  ["[variable("STANDARD_LONG")]"]=>
  string(10) "-73.976303"
  ["[variable("STANDARD_LAT")]"]=>
  string(9) "40.761902"
}
```

Comment: You should really have your properties follow common variable name conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use extended object access notation:

```
$data->{'[question(13), option(0)]'}
```

Or just ask for normal array and use it as normal array.

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: Ahhh... the infamous curly brackets. Thanks!
Out of curiosity, what does that notation mean? Are those instance variables of an object?

Comment: @Emerson: Yes, they are. Check the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php for more information.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo $data->{'[question(13), option(0)]'};
```